# angular 5 и asp .net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2, angular5

Как правильно создать проект на angular 5 и asp .net core mvc? В VS 2017 есть шаблон , но там angular 4 и как бы я не пытался обновить до 5 версии , корректно это сделать не получается (через npm). Через dotnet cli нет возможности создать такой проект. Или подскажите, как правильно обновить шаблон из VS 2017? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Можно все вручную сделать (если захотите я могу рассказать), а можно воспользоваться готовым решением, например : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RebaiHamidaTrabelsi.Angular5TemplateCore2

Comment: спасибо за ответ. этим решением пользовался, в package.json вроде новые версии , а если посмотреть версии модулей в зависимостях после восстановление, то там 4 версии. А через консоль с dotnet cli создает все как нужно, но там не mvc (т.е .нет представлений), а как изменить не могу понять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.talkingdotnet.com/upgrade-angular-4-app-angular-5-visual-studio-2017/ нашел ответ здесь. Обновлять нужно именно через PowerShell, через консоль npm и nodejs не получалось.